# Rails send_data disposition inline doesn't work, csv got auto downloaded instead of open in a new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, content-disposition

I want to allow user to click on a button in my view page and open a new page of a csv file instead of downloading the csv file automatically. This is the button in the view page:

```
<%= link_to "Export as CSV", {:action => "index", :format => :csv}, :target => '_blank' %>
```

When the user clicks the above button, it will trigger the index action in my controller. This is part of the controller's index action:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv do
        send_data @resultCSV, :disposition => 'inline', :filename => 'csv_search_results.csv', type: Mime::CSV
    end
end
```

When I clicked on the button in my Chrome browser, it opens a new tab and immediately close that new tab and begins downloading the csv file.

But I used ":disposition => 'inline'". The csv file is meant to be displayed in the new tab. It should not automatically begins the download. This is not what I want and I don't know what is causing it.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome was not intended to display .csv files by default (At time of writing).
Here's a reference from a google search ("cannot view csv chrome"): 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/bEncfRIUclQ/Dc4aZL2R7loJ

As you are using Rails, if you really need to display it in the browser you might want to create a view with the parsed but ultimately if you want the users to get a csv you might want the users to download it and open it on their own software.